# Error is using opencv with python

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have this code for finding contour in opencv with python

```
im = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

When I try to run this I am getting an error saying

> "ValueError: need more than two values to unpack"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is some documentation mismatch of `cv2.findcontours()` method, it simple returns 2 values: `contours, hierarchy`, so you  should replace the last line with :

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```